# Vue router no muestra el componente anidado

Tags: vue3, vue-router

Tengo esta ruta en Vue router:

```
{
  path: '/profile',
  name: 'profile',
  component: () => import('../pages/profile/ProfilePage.vue'),
  children: [
    {
      path: 'edit',
      name: 'edit',
      component: () => import('../pages/edit/profile/EditProfilePage.vue')
    }
  ],
}
```

si entro a /profile, me muestra el componente profile, pero si entro a /profile/edit, me sigue mostrando el componente profile solamente, si lo remuevo de profile, si me muestra el componente anidado, me pueden indicar que estoy aplicando mal aqui?

Si lo saco del componente anidado si funciona tambien, algo ahi del componente anidado no me esta funcionando

```
{
  path: '/profile/edit',
  name: 'profile',
  component: () => import('../pages/edit/profile/EditProfilePage.vue')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ya entendi como utilizar el router anidado, entonces al componente padre, se tiene que agregar la llamada a

ProfilePage.vue

```
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>
```

El resto quedaria asi:

```
{
  path: '/profile',
  name: 'profile',
  component: () => import('../pages/profile/ProfilePage.vue'),
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      name: 'main',
      component: () => import('../pages/main/profile/ProfilePage.vue')
    },
   {
      path: 'edit',
      name: 'edit',
      component: () => import('../pages/edit/profile/EditProfilePage.vue')
    }
  ],
}
```